# System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider - displaying "&" character

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to set an error message which contains an ampersand via an ErrorProvider. 
First attempt went like this :

```
errorProvider.SetError(someControl, "You have not accepted the Terms & Conditions");
```

This does not display the ampersand character. Googling suggested the following :

```
errorProvider.SetError(someControl, "You have not accepted the Terms &&& Conditions");
```

It works (i.e. displays one ampersand), but I would like to understand *why* it works. Any ideas ?

**EDIT** : for the System.Windows.Forms.Label control, there is a property called : UseMnemonic which can be set to False. Does ErrorProvider have anything like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“&” is a special character in forms that is meant to underline the following character. So if you use it like:

```
myButton.Text = "&Close";
```

it will underline the 'C' character which will also become a hotkey. If you don't want that to happen, you use double ampersand like '&&' in your text.

Comment: I tried two ampersands, but it didn't work. I can't figure out why three are required.

Comment: Triple ampersands will actually underline the ampersand character. Try setting [UseMnemonic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) property to false (if the control supports it), then a single ampersand should suffice.

Comment: two ampersands works for Label.Text, but for ErrorProvider, three seem to be required (at least that's what I am seeing with .net 2.0). Also there doesn't seem to be a UseMnemonic property for ErrorProvider.